# Why do I have to set left and right to 0 in order to horizontally center a control?

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS as follows:

```
.center
{
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

It doesn't work without the

```
right:0;
left:0;
```

(I found that solution in a comment [here](http://www.zachgraeve.com/2006/10/01/center-abosulte-position-div/))

Why?

Comment: I must agree, its annoying that we cannot use align="center" any more, it was just too simple!

Comment: @craig1231: Is that a consequence of HTML5?

Comment: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so bear with me... this whole thing has to do with the [Visual formatting model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html), in particular with the way in which widths and margins are calculated.

There are several things that need to be taken into account, like `display` and `position` (which can all be seen on [section 10.3 of the CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins)).

For your case in particular we are talking about absolutely positioned non-replaced elements (since it is not an image or anything with intrinsic size), so it's section [10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width).

According to your css, you have a defined width, so not `auto`, and both your left and right margins are `auto`. So it boils down to what are the left/right values:

If left/right are defined, so **not auto**, the following rule applies:

> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values (...)

If left/right are not defined, so they default to **auto**, the following rules apply:

First:

> set 'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0 (...)

Second:

> if the 'direction' property of the element establishing the static-position containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the static position, otherwise set 'right' to the static position. Then solve for 'left' (if 'direction is 'rtl') or 'right' (if 'direction' is 'ltr').

So you can see that if you do not define a specific value for left/right, your margins actually become `0` and you end up having the div either to the left or to the right of the container depending on the value of the `direction` property (you can test this by putting something like `html { direction:rtl; }` on your css, the div should go to the right instead of the left when left/right are auto)

However if you do specify the values, in your case 0, the "two margins get equal values" effectively centers the elemement.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> "For absolutely positioned elements, the *top* , *right* , *bottom* and
>   *left* properties specify offsets from the edge of the element's
>   containing block (what the element is positioned relative to). The
>   margin of the element is then positioned **inside these offsets**."

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position)

That's why it works - by setting the `left` and `right` attributes you're stretching the element's offset to be 100%. And inside that 100% width the `margin: auto` works as usual.

Comment: I assumed the default is 100% (I even think I've used it in the past based on that assumption and things worked fine.) Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit unexpected to see "absolute" (which is used when you want to control the position of the element on the site) and then "auto". Nevertheless, you might have a good reason for doing that. I'd suggest that since you're using the style

```
position: absolute;
```

you could center it by specifying the style

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -40px;
```

under the assumption that your component is 80 pixels wide.

Comment: OK, but what if you don't already know the width of that which you are trying to center, or don't want to bother keeping track of it?  Anyway, this doesn't answer the question being asked.

Comment: Good point. Let's assume that we don't know that. In that case i'd ask you WHAT it is OP was trying to achieve. Maybe there's an other approach producing the same result?

Comment: Your solution can create a scrollbar in certain cases. Anyway, I do know the width. (It's not I who downvoted, though.)