# Can I set all offset sides in CSS at once?

Tags: html, css

Instead of having:

```
right:0px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
```

Can I have something like this?

```
sides:0px;
```

Comment: No. I always thought this was a bit strange as there is shorthand for other selectors but I don't make the rules up.

Comment: I'm not sure when you would want to add  to all sides at once, i can understand 2 at a time in corners only, but having a value on 2 opposite sides or having 3/4 would seem a little strange.. It's like fighting to move it right and left at the same time

Comment: @JakeJ It's not *that* strange. You can use them to change the size of an element too, not just to move it. E.g. `data:text/html,<div style="background:green;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0"></div>`.

Comment: @JakeJ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528478/why-do-i-have-to-set-left-and-right-to-0-in-order-to-horizontally-center-a-contr

Comment: @mercator Didn't think of it as a sizing option, I usually use width and height for sizing but I suppose that there's always multiple ways about doing anything

Comment: @ispiro Very strange behaviour, nice read though.. Didn't think that would ever be needed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there does not exist a shorthand `sides` property for setting the offsets. You have to set them all separately.

There are shorthands for other kinds of properties that involve the sides of a box, e.g. [`margin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties), [`padding`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) and [`border`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-properties), but not for the [positional offsets `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#position-props).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a preprocessor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), then yes, you can. If you're using vanilla CSS, then no, *not yet*.

### Example in LESS

```css
.sides (@length) {
  top: @length;
  bottom: @length;
  left: @length;
  right: @length;
}
div {
  .sides(0px);
}
```

### Example in Sass

```css
@mixin sides($length) {
  top: $length;
  bottom: $length;
  left: $length;
  right: $length;
}
div {
 @include sides(0px);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. It wouldn't be very useful anyway, since you hardly ever set all of those values at once and all to the same value. You usually two of them, namely `left` or `right` and `top` or   `bottom` and again rarely to the same value so there is no real way to shorten that.

Comment: but in real shorthand, you can give them all different values... i.e. margin: 10px 15px 25px 0px ... ect

Comment: @MattHintzke What would be the point in adding those kinds of values you used as an example in a real-world scenario. The top,left,right,bottom all move it xxx amount of pixels (or whichever measurement you use) away from that direction, so moving it 10px from the left and then 25 from the right seems a little strange

Comment: I was about to add an answer like this, I couldn't think of a time where you would do all 4 sides for position.

Comment: Yes, but you only set two of them. Something like `left-top: 5px 10px;` is hardly any shorter that `left: 5px; top: 10px;`.

Comment: You can absolutely position a box and set all its offsets to 0, causing it to span the entire size of its container for [an interesting effect](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/DtpPn).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528478/why-do-i-have-to-set-left-and-right-to-0-in-order-to-horizontally-center-a-contr

Comment: @JakeJ Actually I use that syntax a lot. maybe not the example I stated but something like `margin: 20px auto 0px auto` this would give me a centered object with 20px margin on top.. it IS useful

Answer (score -1):

Not with the CSS attributes that you are trying to use, but yes for border, margin, padding, ect.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to position something? It just seems kind of strange to position something with left: 10px and right: 10px.

But no, their is no shortcut... typically you wouldn't position using all of them.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools - see http://w3fools.com for the reasons why. You might have linked to a page that shows correct information, but the site contains a lot of incorrect and misleading information - and linking to the site in any way gives it credibility it does **not** deserve (if you found it via Google, and you have a Google account, you can easily block results from the site) - **edit**, I am not the downvoter, linking to w3schools is not a reason to downvote

Comment: I'll link to whatever site may have the correct content and it written in a clear, correct manner. 

A correct answer comes from my expertise in the field, not from the site in which I chose to reference.

Comment: If you want to refer a site that's regarded across SO as being generally pretty bad, that's your choice and I'm not going to stop you - but I will point it out. (Once again, I was **not** the downvoter)

Comment: [Related meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link)

Answer (score -1):

If you changed the offset to 0px because you want to overwrite other defaults, maybe you want to use:

> position: static

The default positioning for all elements is position:static, which means the element is not positioned and occurs where it normally would in the document.